# Kendo file upload : Without selecting file display upload file button

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have Kendo file uploader as follows:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Upload()
    .Name("files")
    .Multiple(false)
    .Async(a = > a.Save("UploadArtifactFile", "PP", new {
    TeacherEvalID = ViewBag.TeacherEvalID, ObservationID = ViewBag.ObservationID, Accountid = ViewBag.AccountID
})
    .AutoUpload(false))
    .Events(events = > events.Success("onSuccess")

    .Error("onUploadError")
    .Upload("onUpload")))
```

Its initially (when loaded) viewing me as:

[image]

And after selecting file :

[image]

I want that "Upload Files" button to come up at first when this file upload UI is loaded.

I.E. I want Upload Files button below "Select files" in first scenario (when ui is loaded.)

How can i get it?

I checked with events.. but not getting approriate event to do such task.

Please help me.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in a form and adding a submit?  look at this demo of basic usage: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/upload/index  it shows both buttons and no need to second "Upload files" button